# C command line arguments are ints according to my compiler. Whats going on?

Tags: c, io

So I haven't written anything in C for about a year and this morning I thought I'd write something. I /very/ quickly ran into problems. The extremely basic code below doesn't run:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(int argc, char* argv)
 {
        printf("arg is %s \n", argv[1]);
 }
```

I get the following errors

```
gcc dink.c -o dink
dink.c: In function ‘main’:
dink.c:6:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has  type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
./dink menkmenk
make: *** [all] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Whats going on?

EDIT: I'm getting answers as to why the code doesnt work, but I'd still like to know why the compiler thinks im holding an int in the second argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers tell you how to fix the problem.  Here is why you got that particular error message.

C has rules for changing types in expressions... they are converted to other types, automatically, much of the time.  Where I went to college, in the classes I took, these conversions were informally called "promotions" but I guess the correct technical term is "conversions" (see comment from @Steve Jessop below).

Here's an example:

```
float f = 3.14f + 2;
```

In this example, we are requesting that an integer be added to a float.  According to C type rules, the integer value will be converted to float (as part of the "usual automatic conversions" documented in the standard), and then two floats will be added together, giving the same result as if we had typed:

```
float f = 3.14f + 2.0f;
```

And by the way, even more conversions would be happening if we left of the `f` suffixes.  Consider this expression:

```
float f = 3.14 + 2;
```

Since `3.14` was not declared with an `f` suffix, it is a constant of type `double`.  Then the integer `2` is converted to `double`, the addition happens, and the result is a `double`.  But then it must be assigned to a variable of type `float` so it will be converted from `double` to `float`, and you will probably see a compiler warning about a possible loss of precision when converting from `double` to `float`.

Anyway, returning to your question:

When you declared `argv` as type `char *`, and then you referred to `argv[1]`, the type of the expression `argv[1]` was type `char`.  But C converted the type from `char` to `int`, thus leading to the confusing error message.

You can read more on C's type conversion rules here:

http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html

EDIT: Changed the above to consistently use the word "conversion" rather than "promotion" in response to a comment from @Steve Jessop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why did C even try to promote the char to an int here?

Comment: Terminology: the conversion of `2` to `float` in your first example is part of the "usual arithmetic conversions". It's not part of anything that the *standard* calls "promotions", although in English it's reasonable for a value-preserving conversion to a larger type to be called a "promotion". The conversion from `char` to `int` in the questioner's code is because of the "default argument promotions", which are applied to varargs argument expressions (6.5.2.2/7 in C99).

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: There's no trying, only doing. You should be more assertive. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The signature for your `main` is wrong.  `argv` should be an array of strings.  i.e.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
//                           ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more usual to declare argv as `char **argv` or `char *argv[]`.

`char *argv` indicates that argv is a pointer to a `char`, which is rather different.

Thus

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

ought to be more in line with what you'd expect.

Also, it is not preferred to request `argv[1]` as such; you should generally at least check that there is such an argument.